# Net Core - Why exception middleware is so slow?

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

First of all, sorry about my english.

Well, I'm developing a .Net Core Rest Api (I've developed before in asp.net mvc but in net core is the first time ever) and I just faced an strange thing.

The application is developed in various layers: WebApi -> Core <- Infrastructure.

The point is that in the services of the core layer, I decided to trhow some exceptions for some business rules. For example, there are some translatable entities, when you want to create a new entity you must provide a translate for each culture defined in the application. If there is a missing translation I throw an exception way up.

Example of a method:

```
public async Task<CompanyResource> Add(CompanyResource companyResource)
    {
        var cultures = await _cultureRepository.GetAllAsync();
        if (cultures.Any(culture => companyResource.Translations.All(t => t.CultureCode != culture.Code)))
            throw new MissingTranslationsException();

        await _companyResourceRepository.AddAsync(companyResource);

        return companyResource;
    }
```

Now I was wondering how to handle the exceptions in the controller to send to the client the proper httpStatusCode depending on each exception type and a human readable message.

Searching around I found 3 main ways:
- Try/Catch in the method in the controller
- Custom Exception filter
- Custom Exception Midleware

I decided to to for the midleware since it seems to be the best way, to have a centrlized place in all the application to handle the exceptions and to send the messages to the clients so I made this implementation:

```
public class ErrorHandlingMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;

    public ErrorHandlingMiddleware(RequestDelegate next)
    {
        this._next = next;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            await _next(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await HandleExceptionAsync(context, ex);
        }
    }

    private static async Task HandleExceptionAsync(HttpContext context, Exception exception)
    {

        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;

        if (exception is InvalidPermissionsException) code = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        else if (exception is DuplicateEntityException) code = HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
        else if (exception is MissingTranslationsException) code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        else if (exception is ApplicationException) code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new []{ exception.Message });
        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
        context.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        await context.Response.WriteAsync(result);

    }

}
```

Then I wired the middleware to the pipeline:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {

        //...other code

        app.UseMiddleware<ErrorHandlingMiddleware>();

        app.UseHttpsRedirection();

        app.UseMvc();

    }
```

Well, at this point, all worked perfectly, buuuuuut, I just noticed that the response times are far from aceptable when the exceptions are handled by the midleware.

This is the response time when using the middleware:

[image]

Tested several times and the average response time is 460ms +-.

Well, I tough that there must be a way to go faster and then I tried the other 2 methods. With an exceptionFilter atribute:

```
public class HandleExceptionAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
    {
        var code = HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError;
        var exception = context.Exception;

        if (exception is InvalidPermissionsException) code = HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;
        else if (exception is DuplicateEntityException) code = HttpStatusCode.Conflict;
        else if (exception is MissingTranslationsException) code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;
        else if (exception is ApplicationException) code = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest;

        context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
        context.Result = new JsonResult(new[] { exception.Message });

    }
}
```

And when using the filter, the response time went down to 250ms +- average.
I still tough, this is way too slow.. So I went with the last option: Using a try catch inside the action method:

```
[HttpPost]     
    public async Task<IActionResult> Post([FromBody] CompanyResourceDto companyResourceDto)
    {

        if (!ModelState.IsValid) return BadRequest(ModelState);
        var companyresource = _mapper.Map<CompanyResource>(companyResourceDto);

        try
        {
            companyresource = await _resourcesService.Add(companyresource);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return BadRequest(new[] {e.Message});
        }     

        return CreatedAtRoute("Getresource", new { id = companyresource.Id }, _mapper.Map<CompanyResourceDto>(companyresource));
    }
```

And, hell, the average response time in case of exception went down to 85ms +- (which I was excepting from the begining, with the middleware).

I honestly think that the best for manteinaility and separation of concerns is to use the middleware, because I don't want my controllers to be aware from anything than the normal flow..

So, my questions are:

Am I doing something wrong with the midleware? 
If not, why is so slow and which aproach should I take taking in consideration that the response time is critical in this app? 
If yes, what should I change?

Thanks and regards,

Comment: Probably (?) not related to your performance issues, but it's a bad idea to stick something complicated like asynchronous I/O in an exception handler. If code inside an exception handler fails, the original exception is "overwritten" and this can get really hard to troubleshoot. Prefer using simple code that cannot fail; the simplest way of doing that is to set a variable in the handler and check for that after the `try / catch`.

Comment: Why is it that the first method you show is completely different to the last one?

Comment: @JeroenMostert Considering that each `await` calls concurs a small hit in performance, it is definitively related

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the last method is the action method in the web api controller. When I tested using the midleware the try catch boclk is removed from that action method. I copied that code just to show the 3 ways that I tried to handle the exceptions.

Comment: @JeroenMostert but the exception handler is hard to fail, is just a simple type checker that is writing the response in consecuence..

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto its true that each await calls concurs a small hit in performance, but, its th same hit that should occur when using a try catch block inside the action method or when using the exception midleware, I mean, the async await is like 5ms of performance, but it doesnt explain the times diferences between the 3 aproaches..

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I did use the same method for each test, I just wrote the code that I though was relevant to show to ilustrate the 3 diferent tests/aproaches :/

Comment: Writing a response has plenty of (external) failure conditions, including but not limited to a network failure. In this case you probably won't need to investigate stack traces that are the result of a connection disappearing, but if you do it might be completely obscured what the *original* problem was. Save yourself the potential headache.

Comment: Got it @JeroenMostert. Ill take that in mind! Apart from that, do you know why there is that diference between using the exception midleware  versus using a simple try catch inside the action method?

Comment: No, if I knew that I'd write up an answer, or another comment asking for more details. I'm not being pedantic for the sake of it. :-) In general, if you need to get to the bottom of performance characteristics, you'll need to profile.

Comment: This is very likely related to the order of invocation: [Docs on filter order](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#filter-types). 3) Controller returns OK: no-one cares, end the request, 2) Controller throws, handled by filter, filter gets it and returns, 1) Controller throws, goes through filters and middlewares until catched by the exception middleware.

Comment: Are you in debug mode? Chances are the Stack Trace gathering is a performance hit..

Comment: @RobertPerry I found something interesting. Since I was not sure if could be a debud mode issue I went on release mode but still having the performance issue. But, now I've deployed to a stage server in release mode, and the times got beatifully reduced. So i guess you are right and has to be soemthing with the stack trace. What I'm going to investigate now is why in realease mode in my machine the performance issue still hapens.

Comment: Fail to reproduce your issue, please share us a mini demo which  could reproduce your issue.

Comment: @RobertPerry Thanks for point that out. Actually in my case it was Visual Studio gathering the stack trace in both Debug and Release mode. When the application is launched separately (e.g. running the .exe), it works well. I am using ProblemDetailsMiddleware NuGet package to gather exception traces.
The duration is e.g. 1600 ms (in Visual Studio) vs 3 ms (separate process) on request throwing an Exception.

Answer (score 3):

After some tests, I havent found the way to demonstrate it, but it seems the problem is about debug mode in local machine and the stacktrace performance overheat as Robert Perry suggested in the comments.

After setting up the Api in production in a fresh server, the midleware catch all the exceptions in an average time of 15ms +-.

I'll post more info here if I discover why the response time in production mode in my local machine is not the best (maybe it has to do something with the enviroment variable but Im not sure)

Anyways, thank you all.

Regards